# Disable Submit button after clicking once with validation in Magento

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, forms, magento

I need to disable or place a loading image over the form once the submit has been validated. Either one works for me. I have found numerous ways to disable the submit button after you click once, but this does not take in account for validation errors.

I've tried to look this up in many different ways but I can't seem to find something that works.

I am using the default prototype form Magento uses on my current form.

This is what I currently have:

```
var contactForm = new VarienForm('productcontactForm', true);

contactForm.submit = function(){
    if (this.validator.validate()) {
      $('#productcontactForm').submit(function(){
       $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('enabled', 'enabled');
      });
    } else { 
      $('#productcontactForm').submit(function(){
        $('input[type=submit]', this).attr('disabled', 'disabled');
      });
    }
}.bind(contactForm);
```

Comment: Anyone have any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

I'm sorry, I don't run Magento, but I do see a problem. There is no such thing as an 'enabled' attribute in html, javascript or jquery. To enable an input use:

```
<..selector..>.removeAttr('disabled');
```

So to disable an input you add the 'disabled' attribute and to enable it again you remove that attribute.

Comment: Thank you. I will give that a try and see what happens.

Comment: This didn't seem to make a difference at all. Thank you for the suggestion though.

Comment: I expected as much, there are probably other things wrong with your code. Nevertheless the advise is correct.